# How to install ubuntu on a tablet?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I have a tablet that runs Android Ice Cream Sandwich and would like to convert it to run Ubuntu as the Operating System. How easy is it to re install a tablet with Ubuntu?

The tablet is an Model N900

```
CPU Allwinner A13 
FSB 1.5GHz 
OS Android 4.0 ICS 
Memory 512MB DDR3 
Nandflash 8GB 
Extended TF card; U disk, support TF card up to 32GB max 
LCD Display 9 inch capacitive screen, 800*480 
Internet Built-in Ethernet, support WIFI (802.11 a/b/g/n) 
3G support external 3G module 
Camera Front camera 0.3MP 
I/O ports USB port, Headphone Jack, TF card slot 
Touch Screen 5-point capacitive touch screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [Nokia N900](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_n900-2917.php)?

Personally I haven't heard of anybody porting Ubuntu Touch to the Nokia N900. Supposedly it is current [in progress](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). So currently it wouldn't be possible, to easily, install Ubuntu Touch on your device.

If you wish to contribute to the Ubuntu Touch project check out the [porting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting) and get some help from the [ubuntu-phone team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone)

If you aren't talking about the Nokia N900, but instead some other no-name brand tablet. Then it is even more unlikely you'll be able to get it working on your tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up a N900 android tablet and I found this which kind of fits the specs:
http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/9-Android-4-0-Tablet-PC-Allwinner-A13-1GHZ-CPU-1GB-Memory-8GB-16GB-Storage-Capacitive/311779_573646128.html

As far as porting Ubuntu or Ubuntu touch natively, it probably won't happen. But you could try this nice app on the android store: [Ubuntu noroot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cuntubuntu&hl=en)

This app is a compatibility layer that lets you run Ubuntu apps on your tablet in a linux type environment. Due to your low specs however I wouldn't hope for a high performance.